# Highcharts not rendering when property "renderTo" set dynamically

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, highcharts, javascript-objects

I am trying to render a highchart which shows some sensor readings in real time, my issue is that i need to set the "renderTo" property (which accepts the id of the HTML element on which the chart is to be rendered) dynamically. What i mean to say is that:

Instead of doing this: **renderTo: 'container'**

I need to do: **var container = 'container'**

and then: **renderTo: container**

but it gives an error saying that it could not find the HTML element in which the chart is to be rendered.

THIS IS HOW ITS DONE IN THE DOCS

```
Highcharts.chart({
    chart: {
        type: 'spline',
        animation: Highcharts.svg,
        marginRight: 10,
        renderTo: 'container' <---
    }
}
```

WHAT I NEED TO DO

```
var container = 'container'

Highcharts.chart({
    chart: {
    type: 'spline',
    animation: Highcharts.svg,
    marginRight: 10,
    renderTo: container // where container can be equal to container1 , container2, container3 and so on
    }
}
```

How can i do this ?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanx

**EDIT 1:** Okay so i got the element reference by the method described by **Deep3015** and the chart is being rendered but i am now facing another issue. When i use **document.getElementById('container')** it works fine, but returns null when i do this **document.getElementById(container)** , please refer to the portion of code below.

```
if(status=='1'){
  Highcharts.setOptions({
  global: {
      useUTC: false
  }
  });
  var containerid = tr.find('td').eq(1).text(); // This gives me the id of the container
  var container = document.getElementById('12:23:12:32:34'); // This works (when id is hard coded)
  var container = document.getElementById(containerid); // This does not
  console.log(container); // container gets the reference when id is hard coded and is null when id is passed as a variable 
  console.log(containerid); // shows the correct retrieved id in both cases
  Highcharts.chart({  
  chart: {
      type: 'spline',
      renderTo:container,
      animation: Highcharts.svg,
      marginRight: 10
    }
  });
}
```

What could possibly be wrong ?

Comment: for this you can use `var container = document.getElementById('container')` where `'container'` can be  passed dynamically

Comment: check this simple example http://jsfiddle.net/Lofeu4n9/

Comment: You have to be sure that you render a chart after the element is created. Your example does not have right to not work unless you do something else which  you did not post - https://jsfiddle.net/58r4je25/

Comment: @Deep3015 i did as you advised and it worked but now i'm facing another issue, please refer to EDIT 1

Comment: @morganfree my previous issue is resolved but i'm now facing another one, please refer to EDIT 1

Comment: @BadarKhan Iam getting proper element https://jsfiddle.net/7j6zepbq/